# tried to execute a query that does not include the specified expression 'CodeProduct' as part of an aggregate function

Tags: sql, ms-access

why does an error appear what is wrong in my code, please guide me

Thanks

```vb
Private itrservice As New StocksoutService()
 Public Function GetStockin() As IEnumerable(Of Stocksout)
            Dim sql = "SELECT Stocksout.Invno AS [Invno],StocksoutDetail.CodeProduct AS [CodeProduct] FROM Stocksout INNER JOIN StocksoutDetail ON Stocksout.Invno = StocksoutDetail.Invno GROUP BY Stocksout.Invno"
            Using _conn = New OleDbConnection(DbContext.GetOledbConnectionString())
                Return _conn.Query(Of Stocksout)(sql).ToList()
            End Using
        End Function
            grid.DataSource = itrservice.GetStockin()
```

Comment: This is purely a SQL question. It has nothing to do with VB.NET or Dapper. The issue would be the same no matter how you executed that query.

Comment: @jmcilhinney , means something is wrong with the SQL query I created

Comment: Yes, exactly as the error message is telling you. You tried to execute an invalid query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you are selecting multiple columns (two, in this case) and trying to group by one of them without specifying how to aggregate the others. If you group by `Stocksout.Invno` then you need to aggregate `StocksoutDetail.CodeProduct`, which is exactly what the error message is telling you that you haven't done. Aggregate functions are things like `COUNT`, `MAX`, `SUM`, etc.

Comment: I want to display "StocksoutDetail.CodeProduct" by doing an inner join based on "invno"

Comment: @pret, if that's all you want then why are you grouping at all? If you don't want to group on that column then don't. If you do want to group on that column then you need to aggregate the other column. It's one or the other.

Comment: You may use ``max(StocksoutDetail.CodeProduct) AS [CodeProduct]``. All columns, not included in GROUP BY clause, need to wrap by aggregate functions.

Comment: @pret, there are presumably multiple CodeProduct values for each Invno value. How do you want them combined? Do you want them combined at all? That will determine whether you should be grouping and, if so, what aggregate function you should be using. If you're not sure, edit your question and provide a small example of data for the two tables and your desired output.

Comment: @jmcilhinney , Thank you for your answer and your guide, Sorry I'm late Reply